# How to set the id field using factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I've this setup.

```
class Musicbrain < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id
  validates_presence_of :id
end

create_table "musicbrains", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.string  "id",        null: false
end

factory(:musicbrain) do
  sequence(:id) {|n| "79239441-bfd5-4981-a70c-55c3f15c128#{n}"}
end
```

The problem is that this spec always fails.

```
it "should set id" do
  build(:musicbrain, id: "79239441-bfd5-4981-a70c-55c3f15c1287").should be_valid
end
```

`Musicbrain#id` is always nil, why is that?

- Rails 4.0.0
- factory_girl 4.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem.

```
class Musicbrain < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id
  validates_presence_of :id
  self.primary_key = "id"
end
```

Comment: I just used this to solve my UUID primary keys. Very weird...it shouldn't need this, but you just fixed my problem. Thank you!